# Validate Contact name on Quote object

Tags: trigger, validation, quote

How do you validate if the Contact name field is left empty or not on Quote? I do see that, its a lookup field and using the code as below on trigger always return false.

```
for (Quote objQuote : Trigger.new) {
    if(objQuote.Contact == null) {
         objQuote.addError('Contact is missing');
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the lookup field. Contact represents the relationship, which is always null in a trigger (you can query for it if you need it). The field you need to check is ContactId.